# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean factory must be instance of ListableBeanFactory, was null

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm creating a state machine object using the provided builder as follows:

[10.2 State Machine via Builder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#state-machine-via-builder)


I'm seeing the following exception:

> ERROR org.springframework.statemachine.support.StateMachineObjectSupport  - Unable to initialize annotation handlers
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean factory must be instance of ListableBeanFactory, was null

The exception isn't preventing the state machine from functioning as expected.  However, I would like to get down to the bottom of why I'm seeing this.

Anyone know how I can stop this exception from showing?

Thanks.

Comment: What version you're using? That was changed in 1.1.x to log on info level as it's not really an error. Notifocation simply means that no annotation processing(no callback to annotated methods) will happen as beanfactory is not present, which usually is a case if using builder.

Comment: Using, 1.1.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get a solution for this.

I autowired the the Spring application context into my class.  I then extracted the AutowireCapableBeanFactory from this and set this up inside the builder.  As follows:

```
   @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

     private void buildStateMachine() throws Exception {
        Builder<EnquiryStatus, Event> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
        builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().beanFactory(appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().beanFactory(new StaticListableBeanFactory());
```