# Error while starting state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

while calling `statemachine.start()` Iam always getting the below stack trace.But it's not stopping my state machine execution though, since Iam not using any annotation for state transitions, state entry etc.
Please help me in fixing this error.

```
19:41:56.515 ERROR o.s.s.s.StateMachineObjectSupport - Unable to initialize annotation handlers
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean factory must be instance of ListableBeanFactory, was null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.setBeanFactory(StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.java:93) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.StateMachineObjectSupport.doStart(StateMachineObjectSupport.java:66) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.doStart(AbstractStateMachine.java:317) [spring-statemachine-core-1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.LifecycleObjectSupport.start(LifecycleObjectSupport.java:120) [spring-statemachine-core-1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.tiaa.devops.process.delegate.StateMachineDelegateImpl.execute(StateMachineDelegateImpl.java:103) [classes/:na]
    at org.tiaa.devops.process.delegate.StateMachineDelegateImpl.executePipeline(StateMachineDelegateImpl.java:67) [classes/:na]
    at org.tiaa.devops.process.delegate.StateMachineDelegateImpl.lambda$0(StateMachineDelegateImpl.java:59) [classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Please include the code that leads to this exception. It's nearly impossible to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: Could this be a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925352/java-lang-illegalstateexception-bean-factory-must-be-instance-of-listablebeanfa

Comment: Thanks! This thread helped me in fixing the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925352/java-lang-illegalstateexception-bean-factory-must-be-instance-of-listablebeanfa

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a solution for this.

I autowired the the Spring application context into my class.  I then extracted the AutowireCapableBeanFactory from this and set this up inside the builder.  As follows:

```
   @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

     private void buildStateMachine() throws Exception {
        Builder<EnquiryStatus, Event> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
        builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().beanFactory(appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
     }
```

(copied verbatim from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926670/122441 )